# TeamCity Access Build Results of Last Successful Build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there a way to browse the build artifacts of the last successful run?

I was able to figure this one out: `https://teamcity/repository/downloadAll/<project_name>/.lastSuccessful/<artifact_path>?branch=%3Cdefault%3E`

But am looking for a way to browse the files and selectively download ie this view: `https://teamcity/buildConfiguration/<project_name>/<build_id>?buildTab=artifacts`

I thought maybe replacing the `build_id` with `.lastSuccessful` might do it but no dice.

[This link](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts) describes how to download artifacts, but I would like to be able to browse the results so I can select a subset of artifacts to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing like *a normal GUI view* (not a file directory listing) can be done via `viewLog` link which will redirect to the link you described:

```
http://teamcity/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=<project_name>&tab=artifacts
```